# WPF Некорректная ширина PART_SelectionRange

Tags: wpf, slider, wpf-шаблоны

Для `Slider` переопределил шаблон, получилось почти то, что нужно

```
<Style x:Key="customSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0,0,10,10" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderThickness="0"
                                CornerRadius="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Height="4" Grid.Row="1" Background="#D8DEE4" />
                        <Border x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Grid.Row="1"
                                CornerRadius="2" Height="4" Background="#bac7d4"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="0"/>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"
                                              BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                    <RepeatButton.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                                        <Border Height="4" CornerRadius="2" Background="#5F7E9E"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </RepeatButton.Style>
                                </RepeatButton>
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>

                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="Black">
                                    <Thumb.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                        <Ellipse Fill="#FF5C7CA1" Height="8" Width="8"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Thumb.Style>
                                </Thumb>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- ... -->

<Slider Name="Volume_Slider" Style="{StaticResource customSlider}"
        SelectionEnd="1" Maximum="1" TickFrequency="0.02"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Value="0.5"/>
```

Но получил следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, `SelectionRange` должен быть на всю ширину слайдера, но этого не происходит. Для любой ширины слайдера ширина selection меньше ширины слайдера на 8 пикселей(в данной ситуации), по сути, ничего лишнего нет. В чем может быть причина и как это решить?

Comment: Проще всего подсмотреть в Snoop'е, какой именно элемент имеет неправильную ширину.

Comment: В смысле "какой"? в <Border x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" переопределяю SelectionRange

Answer (score 1):

Разница в 8 — это ширина `Thumb`'а. Это поведение by design ([reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Slider.cs,1020)). (Это легко проверить, поменяв размеры `Thumb`'а.)

Насколько я понимаю, у вас этот промежуток должен покрываться Thumb'ом, по задумке авторов контрола.

Comment: Какое решение? Canvas не подходит вместо Grid, что еще есть для абсолютного позицирования?

Comment: @Ni55aN: А почему бы не показать Thumb на месте этих 8 пикселей?

Comment: @Ni55aN: Исходя из [этого](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Slider.cs,1030), возможно, и правда нужно поместить `PART_SelectionRange` в `Canvas`.